# Traverse a IEnumerable<T> with children to find a specific entry

Tags: c#

in an mvc application I've got a menu composed of the following structure

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Action {get;set;}
    public string Controller {get;set;}
    public string Text {get;set;}
    public List<MenuItem> Children {get;set;}
}
```

Consider a simple compisition of

```
Root
\-Item1
\-Item2
  \-Item2_1
  \-Item2_2
    \-Item_2_2_1
    \-Item_2_2_2
\-Item3
```

I want to get the item Item_2_2_2 (consider it has Action="Index", Controller="ABC")

How can I write a function (or better extension method of T) that iterates trought the collection and get the item it matches that condition ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question is about "get the items matches on a condition", it's possible to directly include the search criteria into the recursion, and by this way, optimize the graph traversal by `yielding` only once over the collection :

Moreover, since you can use a .Take(10) operator over the result, and since there are different ways of walking over a graph, I included a depth-first / breadth-first option.

Moreover bis, since we are on Stackoverflow, and even if the default max stack size on .Net is of 1MB, it's improbable but not impossible to throw a StackOverflowException. So here's also a safe, non-recursive version of the depth-first graph traversal.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(this T node, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childs, Func<T, bool> condition, GraphTraversal mode = GraphTraversal.DepthFirst)
{
    if (node == null || childs == null || condition == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    if (mode == GraphTraversal.DepthFirst)
        return node.depthFirstTraversal(childs, condition);
    else if (mode == GraphTraversal.DepthFirstNoStackOverflow)
        return node.depthFirstTraversalWithoutStackoverflow(childs, condition);
    else
        return node.breadthFirstTraversal(childs, condition);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> depthFirstTraversal<T>(this T node, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childs, Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    IEnumerable<T> childrens = childs(node);
    if (childrens == null)
        yield break;
    if (condition(node))
        yield return node;
    foreach (T i in childrens)
    {
        foreach (T j in depthFirstTraversal(i, childs, condition))
        {
            if (condition(j))
                yield return j;
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> breadthFirstTraversal<T>(this T node, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childs, Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    queue.Enqueue(node);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        T currentnode = queue.Dequeue();
        if (condition(currentnode))
            yield return currentnode;
        IEnumerable<T> childrens = childs(currentnode);
        if (childrens != null)
        {
            foreach (T child in childrens)
                queue.Enqueue(child);
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> depthFirstTraversalWithoutStackoverflow<T>(this T node, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childs, Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    Stack<T> stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(node);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        T currentnode = stack.Pop();
        if (condition(currentnode))
            yield return currentnode;
        var childrens = childs(currentnode);
        if (childrens != null)
        {
            foreach (var child in childrens)
                stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
}

public enum GraphTraversal { DepthFirst, DepthFirstNoStackOverflow, BreadthFirst }
```

You use it like this :

```
var found = rootItem.Search(i => i.Children, i => i.Action == "Index" && i.Controller == "ABC");
```

Alex's solution is good, but when doing

```
items.Flatten(i => i.Children).Where(i => ...
```

the collection is fully `yielded` one time with `Flatten`, and one other time with `Where`, and lacks some null checks.

As Alex pointed it, the iteration is deferred, but since each `IEnumerable<T>` operator (and each `foreach`) need to call enumerator.GetNext(), so there will be performance improvement by integrating the predicate directly into the recursion loop.

Comment: Thanks both for the solution I prefer Sharped one since I can specify the children to iterate on... I'm not at pc right now...give a try asap  this!

Comment: No, since `Flatten` uses `yield return` iteration is deferred. Thus, if you use `items.Flatten(i => i.Children).First(i => ...`, you iterate only until your first match.

Comment: Even if iteration is deferred, there are 2X more calls to enumerator.MoveNext(). For N items in the graph, there are N calls in the Flatten method, and N calls in Where method.

Comment: Take a look at how is internally made the Where() operator : http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/c7d6c8b578f62bef.html

Comment: Alex, you give me an idea by mentioning `First()` :)

Comment: I'm still not convinced. I tried to understand your concerns with some breakpoints within `Flatten`; I created even a custom Enumerator to verify this: if i just call `Flatten`, there isn't a single call to `MoveNext`; if i create a hierarchy with items "a", "b", "c", "d" and call `Flatten(...).First(... == "b")`, there is just one call for "a" and one call for "b", which matches my understanding for 'yield return'. Don't get me wrong, your solution is good, but "the collection is fully yielded one time with Flatten" is imho wrong.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but internally a foreach uses something like `while (enumerator.MoveNext())`. And in the `WhereEnumerableIterator` class I mentioned, it's the same kind of implementation. So I think there is really a little performance overhead by not including the predicate. Anyway, I think the best answer can only be a performance test.

Answer (score 6):

You can write an extension method to "flatten" hierarchies...

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T value, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> inner) {
    foreach (var i in inner(value)) {
        foreach (var j in Flatten(i, inner)) {
            yield return j;
        }
    }
    yield return value;
}
```

...then use ordinary LINQ:

```
items.Flatten(i => i.Children).Where(i => ...
```